# Find largest files of a particular owner

Tags: files, find, disk-usage

I accidentally chown'd my entire file system to a particular user, after correcting the issue I've found disk space still being consumed by that particular user's files even though their account directory is empty, so they still have files scattered throughout.

My question is: can I scan my entire directory from / for the largest files owned by user 'exampleuser'?

Comment: You should reinstall. Sounds hard, but it's the only correct and save way to handle this, if you chowned the whole system. You opened 1000 security holes with that, now you may closed 950. You can never be sure that you closed all.

Comment: How would that solve the problem of some files being mis-owned? Wouldn't they keep the same ownership?

Comment: By "chown'd my entire file system", you meant somthing like `chown -R user:group /`? If yes, a reinstallation deletes all files and copies them new (with the correct ownership).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command for this. To search your entire filesystem for files owned by user exampleuser use:

```
$ sudo find / -user exampleuser
```

If you want search for large files add the `-size` option:

```
$ sudo find / -user exampleuser -size +10000k
```

This: `+10000k` will find files greater than 10,000 kilobytes in size.

Comment: (note that that `k` suffix is not standard/portable (and where it's supported, `M`/`G` ones would be as well). use `-size +10240000c` portably).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find / -user <someuser> -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -rn | head -1
```

The above uses GNU `find(1)` and assumes no filenames have embedded newlines.  It also has to be run as root (otherwise it wouldn't be able to read all directories).